# Creating a React JS progress bar based on progress of Flask microservice?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, sockets, flask

I'm trying to create a progress bar in React by calling a Flask microservice with Python.

I don't have problems to display the component in the frontend but I don't know if:

- Is possible to get a response with the progress of a script done in a
  Flask microservice?
- Can a socket communication be established between Javascript and Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have broadly speaking three choices:

- Websockets with flask-websockets
  `https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/`
- ServerSentEvents
  `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events`
- Having the process update an in-memory cache that you can poll through another ingress route.

The first and second are difficult if you run Flask properly with WSGI.